# How to obtain the closest, lowest palindrome of a given number

Tags: python, math, palindrome

I am trying to modify the answer to give me the closest lowest palindrome number.

I have tried modifying the answer to this:

```
     def lowest(n):
        s = str(n + 1)
        l = len(s)
        if s[:l//2][::-1] < s[(l+1)//2:]:
            head = str(int(s[:(l+1)//2]))
        else:
            head = s[:(l+1)//2]
        print int(head + head[:l//2][::-1])
```

But for the number 1000, it still returns 1001. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1001 is a palindrome, what's your issue ?

Comment: 'closest, lowest' palindrome to 1000 is 999

Comment: Ah yes, sorry ! I read too fast. Then your algorithm is not adaptable ! It's taking half of the number and compare it to the other to determine which of both palindrome option is the lowest. But for the lowest one, you have the issue that it can be shorter (less char required to write it), as in your example.

Comment: Try modifying the code in the linked answer to produce the *previous palindrome* and then make a wrapper function to run both functions and compare the absolute difference between their results and the input number so you return the closest number (and the smallest if there's a tie). Might be not fastest approach but gets the job done and don't forget that "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: I think he always want the lowest but getting it is the issue. One option may be to reduce your number by 10% and iterate on palindrome greater than it until you find the last one smaller than your initial number. Quite ugly though, I hope there's a more elegant solution. I find your question interesting anyway. Doesn't it deserve the `math` tag ?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for the **previous** palindrome, you have invert a couple of signals in the linked answer and add an edge-case exception (for 10^k+1, for all even k>0)

```
def prev_palindrome(n):
    s = str(n - 1)
    l = len(s)
    if s[:l//2][::-1] > s[(l+1)//2:]:
        head = str(int(s[:(l+1)//2])-1)
    else:
        head = s[:(l+1)//2]
    if len(head) < l/2:
        return int(head + '9' + head[:l//2][::-1]) #edge case
    else:
        return int(head + head[:l//2][::-1])
```

If you want the **closest** you can try:

```
nxt = next_palindrome(n)
prv = prev_palindrome(n)

if abs(prv-n) <= abs(nxt-n):
    print prv
else:
    print nxt
```

Please note that both `next_palindrome` and `prev_palindrome` returns are *strictly* higher/lower than `n`.

Comment: Note that if `n` is a palindrome, it answers `n` (with `s = str(n - 2)` it excludes `n` and answers the closest strictly lower than `n`)